# How to get number of worker, cores, ram from HDI cluster

Tags: linux, shell, azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-rm-template

Here is my scenario. I am creating HDI cluster and installing my custom application using ARM template.

I need following values to be configured for my application using Shell script. Installing my application using CustomScript option in ARM template.

> Number of worker nodes
>
> Number of cores per worker node
>
> RAM per worker node
>
> RAM per head node
>
> Number of cores per worker node

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Ambari REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-manage-ambari-rest-api) to get number of worker nodes.

```
PASSWORD=<>
CLUSTERNAME=<>
#Worker nodes
  curl -u admin:$PASSWORD -sS -G "https://$CLUSTERNAME.azurehdinsight.net/api/v1/clusters/$CLUSTERNAME/services/HDFS/components/DATANODE">worker.txt
cat worker.txt |grep total_count|awk -F: '{print $2}'|sed 's/\,//g'
```

> RAM per worker node

Do you mean the VM's max RAM? If yes, every worker node VM should have the same RAM. VM's RAM and cores are decided to VM's size. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/sizes-general). If you want to achieve it with script. I suggest you could write a configure file, such as

```
Standard_DS1_v2 1   3.5

Standard_DS2_v2 2   7
```

You could get core and MEM by using awk, it is easy. Such is an example.

```
mem=`cat configure.txt|grep "Standard_DS1_v2"|awk '{print $3}`
```

Comment: @karan I test use API, I don't find total MEM and CPU cores in it. You also could test.

Comment: Is there an option to fetch RAM and CPU cores of worker node by using any config file reside in HDI cluster such as yarn-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml,core-site.xml

Comment: I don't find them. You could try to search. If you could not find them. You could create a configure file.